# solution by separation of variables?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

When solving a PDE suppose:
$$
u_x+u_y=(x+y)u
$$
I know you are supposed to solve by supposing :
$$
u=F(x).G(y)
$$

when F(x) and G(y) was obtained after solving, Why is the solution written as the sum instead of product. The final result is written as the sum like so :
$$
u=F(x)+G(y)
$$

Is this how it's supposed to be? Or are my class notes poorly taken?

Comment: Erm, it seems that you misplaced the words "sum" and "product" in some places, especially right in front of your last formula.

Comment: You can try both methods and see which gives you something useful. Neither is a "best 100% method  ™"... If you assume it's a sum, then (e.g.) $u_x = F'$. If you assume it's a product, then $u_x = F' \cdot G$. Both of these will restrict the solutions you can get... Anyway, separation of variables usually refers to the product one.

Comment: Assuming I am taking the product. The final result should be u=F.G ? after solving for F and G that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that direct separation of variables is convenient. But separation of variables works well after a change of variables.

HINT :

Change of variables $\begin{cases} s=y-x \\t=xy \end{cases}$

I must confesse that I cheated: first I solved it thanks to the method of characteristics which leads to $u(x,y)=e^{xy}f(y-x)$ were $f$ is any differentiable function.